# Which clause's column need to be indexed?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

In the below pattern of `select` query:

```
        ┌┐           ↘ ┌┐ ⎫┌┐      ┌┐
        ├┤           ↗ └┘ ⎭└┘    → └┘
        ├┤    ┌┐
        ├┤ →  ├┤       ┌┐ ⎫
        ├┤    └┘     ↘ ├┤ ⎪               ↘  ┌┐
        ├┤           ↗ ├┤ ⎪┌┐             ↗  ├┤
        ├┤  → ┌┐     ↘ ├┤ ⎪└┘             ↘  └┘
        ├┤    └┘       └┘ ⎭                         LIMIT
        ├┤  WHERE   GROUP BY    HAVING   ORDER BY   OFFSET
        ├┤
        ├┤  → ┌┐       ┌┐ ⎫
        ├┤    ├┤     ↗ ├┤ ⎪┌┐      ┌┐
        ├┤    └┘     ↘ ├┤ ⎪└┘    → └┘
        ├┤  → ┌┐     ↗ └┘ ⎭
        ├┤    └┘
        ├┤    ┌┐
        └┘    └┘
```

---

How do I decide, which clause's column requires indexing to improve performance? Is it `ORDER BY`?

Comment: No, you use the index in the first place to find the rows of interest. So it's `WHERE`. Next to consider would be `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That's a nice graphic representation by the way. In shows the phases a query gets through from left to right. And the index is built in the same order.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner When we create index `i` on a table(`t`) column, do we need to run `select` query on `i` or `t`? after indexing

Comment: On the table. The query doesn't change. An index does not appear in a query. Indexes are used behind the scenes, so to say, and are an offer to the DBMS to find a way to access a table's data quickly The DBMS may or may not use one or more of the available indexes for the tables in a query. If at some point in time we decide to introduce an (additional) index for a table, it can happen that not only the query we had in mind runs faster, but several others, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a concrete example: The orders table contains product orders placed with a supplier.

```
select product_number, sum(amount) as total
from orders
where order_date > date '2020-01-01'
and supplier_number = 1234
group by product_number
having sum(amount) > 100
order by product_number;
```

We select from the orders table, but are only interested in certain orders, particularily those of 2020 and regarding supplier 1234. In order to find the rows quickly, you'd index the date and the supplier. And as it's several dates, but only one supplier we are looking for, we want supplier before date in the index:

```
create index idx on orders (supplier_number, order_date);
```

Once the DBMS has found these rows, it wants to sum up ordered amounts per product. So, we might add the product_number to the index, because we know the DBMS needs this next to get the groups.

```
create index idx on orders (supplier_number, order_date, product_number);
```

Then the sums are built and only those products with a total amount of more than 100 are kept. We cannot index that; it's a result from the aggregation. We can still put the amount in the index, though. In that case the DBMS wouldn't even have to read the table, because all the information needed for the query is already in the index. This is called a covering index.

```
create index idx on orders (supplier_number, order_date, product_number, amount);
```

Comment: Does `create index` create a B+ tree internally? for fast search traversal..

Comment: That may depend on the DBMS, but yes, a b-tree is usually the default index type.

Answer (score 1):

Where clause's column requires indexing
Because you need to fetch data based on condition.